# Bootbox, two modal windows - one above another

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootbox

I have two bootbox modal windows - parent and child.
If user enters wrong data and try to save the parent modal window, the child window appears.
The problem is - when the child window appears, it's still possible to click on the parent modal window buttons.
How can I fix it? The parent window controls must be disabled when the child modal opened.

Thanks a lot,

Michael

Comment: Please post some of your code to show what you've done. It might help us know where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice! Thanks a lot!
But solution is more simple.. I changed the z-index of the above window.
Example:
z-index of the **parent** window is 1050.
I've added style to my css file with following rows:
//div.bootbox.modal.fade... is the child modal window

```
    div.bootbox.modal.fade.in {
         z-index:1070;
 }
```

//div.bootbox.modal.fade.in + div - is the next div that fades the body

```
div.bootbox.modal.fade.in + div {
     z-index:1060;
 }
```

Thanks a lot!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

`parent=bootbox.dialog(/*your code*/);`

put following code in callback of button creating child modal

```
parent.find('button').prop("disabled",true);
```

put following code in callback of closing callback

```
parent.find('button').prop("disabled",false);
```

eg.

```
$('button calling child').click(function(e)
{    
    parent.find('button').prop("disabled",true);
   bootbox.dialog(
   {
    main:
      {
        callback:function(e)
        {
           parent.find('button').prop("disabled",false);
        }
      }
    });
});
```